# Angular2: Template variables with custom values

Tags: javascript, angular

I understand that I can assign local template variables to hold element reference like following

```
<input #myInput />
```

But can I declare a variable with custom value?

For example:

```
<!-- Somewhere I do #obj = model.data.something -->

<input [(ngModel)]="obj.inputA" >
<input [(ngModel)]="obj.inputB" >
```

Instead of doing

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.data.something.inputA" >
<input [(ngModel)]="model.data.something.inputB" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare a variable with a custom value.

A template variable

- can refer to the element or component it was applied to
- can refer to a specific directive (if one or more are applied to an element) by referring to its `exportAs: 'xxx'` property `#myVar="xxx"`
- can be declared by structural directives like `*ngFor="let x of y; let i=index"`

There is an open issue to support assigning custom expressions as well https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2451